# Seemingly discipline-wide dismissal of Linguistic Relativity and Post-Structuralism: Who still works with and supports these theories?

Tags: theoretical-linguistics, philosophy-of-language, history-of-linguistics, sapir-whorf-hypothesis, structural-linguistics

Many academics appear to immediately dismiss the mention of linguistic relativity/ Sapir-Whorf hypothesis because its been... supposedly debunked? I am wondering if the theory's critics offer a reworked/stronger theory in it's place? Or, I'm hoping to find scholars who still accept/work with/build on the theory. Same goes for post-structuralism and deconstruction.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by linguistic relativity/Sapir-Whorf? Evidence seems pretty strong that people can comprehend things they don't have words for (sorry Orwell fans), but also evidence seems pretty strong that people categorize things based on the words they know (see the famous Kay and Berlin color study).

Comment: In other words, it's not as simple as "thought is entirely determined by language" versus "thought is completely separate from language". So we'll need to know more details of the particular version of linguistic relativity you're talking about to give a useful answer.

Comment: It seems as if the question of linguistic relativity (being-- our language (within mind and verbally) co-creates our reality) is not considered a post-structuralist concept. I feel as if it is one! Isn't the theory claiming that the landscape of language is a central arena where various dialects/ native languages literally co-create with their users, to some extent, non-permeable realities?

Comment: Post-structuralism and deconstruction aren't even linguistic theories, so we have no dog in that fight. The Sapir/Whorf hypothesis is kind of a historical fiction (there was no such thing), but some of the ideas promulgated under that label have been rehabilitated in modern theory. You might try stating a hypothesis of your own and asking for support / refutation, otherwise you'll just get stuck in a quagmire of exegesis of an idea that nobody actually believed in. Or, pick a specific quote from a linguist like Sapir or Whorf.

Comment: Indeed. You're welcome to use my favorite quote from Sapir (_Language_) "Everything that we have so far seen to be true of language points to the fact that it is the most significant and colossal work that the human spirit has evolved -- nothing short of a finished form of expression for all communicable experience. This form may be endlessly varied by the individual without thereby losing its distinctive contours; and it is constantly reshaping itself as is all art. Language is the most massive and inclusive art we know, a mountainous and anonymous work of unconscious generations."

Comment: Yes, thank you, I will add that to my rolodex. To Draconis, I hadn't implied that Post-structuralism was a linguistic theory. I was merely considering how it is a theory still acclaimed and respected that in ways upholds the Sapir-Whorf hypothesis (or maybe what I mean is linguistic relativity though I naively assumed those were interchangeable)

Comment: Where do you find Post-structuralism acclaimed and respected in linguistic thought, discourse, or literature? It's not about language, and most linguists ignore it.

Comment: @jlawler  I did not say Post-structuralism is acclaimed by linguists. I said that I feel like linguistic relativity and Sapir-Whorf hypothesis aligns with post-structualism. So that is inverse from what you said.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what you mean. "Linguistic relativity" and "Sapir-Whorf hypothesis" are, as noted, inexact memes and not scientific hypotheses; in this they can be said to "align with" Post-structuralism, which is also not a scientific hypothesis, at least not about human language. But being unclear is not much of an alignment.